# Problem with asynchronous code returning wrong variable

Tags: ajax, callback

I'm new to coding using AJAX, and cannot understand why the following asynchronous function which uses a callback will not work properly. The variable PC is global, and set to PC = 666 for tests. PC should be assigned the value of 1 which is read from an XML file. The code I am using is below.

```
function makePlaceRequest(XMLaddress, callback) {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // alert('Starting XML read');
        if (!httpRequest) {
            alert('Warning :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
            return false;
        }

        // httpRequest.onreadystatechange = getPlace;

        // State changes

        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            try {
                if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                        var xmldoc = httpRequest.responseXML;
                        var root_node = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('placecode').item(0);
                        PC = root_node.firstChild.data;
                        // callback();
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
                    }
                }
            }
            catch( e ) {
                alert('Caught Exception: ' + e.description);
            }
        }

        httpRequest.open('GET', XMLaddress);
        // httpRequest.open('GET', '/xml/Places.xml');
        httpRequest.send();

        callback();
    }

    makePlaceRequest('/xml/Places.xml', function() {
        alert(PC);
        alert('Completed XML read');
        alert(PC);
    });
```

I call the function as follows: `makePlaceRequest('/xml/Places.xml');`
The first (PC) alert displays 666, i.e. the callback is being invoked before the XML file has been successfully read, and the second PC alert displays the correct value, i.e. 1
I presume the latter happens because of the delay introduced by the info message (Completed XML read). I cannot understand why the callback function is invoked at all before the processing has completed.

Answer (score 0):

The call to httpRequest.send() is asynchronous and as such will not wait for the AJAX call to complete. Consequently callback() is highly likely to be invoked before the AJAX call receives a response and that response is handled.

When a response is received the program flow will be interrupted to run the onreadystatechange handler. When the onreadystatechange handler has finished running the interrupted program flow resumes.

The commented out callback() within the onreadystatechange handler would ensure that your callback() is only invoked after a response is received and processed.

Comment: The problem is that when I enable the commented callback() and comment out the one after  httpRequest.send() the app throws an exception: Caught Exception: undefined, which suggests something messes up in the 'try' block